# PHP multiple requests / Jplayer

Tags: php, http, jplayer

I get some problems when I use jPlayer plugin on my tablet: there is a constant "progress" event, which is raising endlessly. I noticed also that there are several requests to my server, some of them are pending, some 206 (partial content). Then I just tried to download directly my audio file like this: http://www.mysite.com/uploads/audio.wav, and I saw 3 requests:

1. cancelled
2. pending
3. 206

I think that it's not a normal behavior, shouldn't I get just one 200 OK request?

Well, the main problem is that constant progress event on tablet causes some problems. I don't have such thing on my laptop though.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with m4a files. Just posted to their Google Group